# Add last mistake to dictionary with flyspell and ispell

Tags: flyspell, ispell, spell-checking

`flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word` is a great way to quickly correct mistakes in a buffer. I get a lot of false positives though, and I would like to quickly add them to my dictionary in an analogous way.

How can I make a command to do this? Confusingly, `flyspell-auto-correct-previous-pos` is always `nil` for me.

Comment: You can have a look here http://endlessparentheses.com/ispell-and-abbrev-the-perfect-auto-correct.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly this should solve it. The `add-false-postive` command jumps back to the previous error, adds it to the dict, cleans up and jumps back.

```el
(defun goto-previous-spelling-error ()
  "Go to previous spelling error."
  (interactive)
  (push-mark (point) t nil)
  (let ((pos (point))
        (min (point-min)))
    (while (and (> pos min)
                (let ((ovs (overlays-at pos))
                      (r '()))
                  (while (and (not r) (consp ovs))
                    (if (flyspell-overlay-p (car ovs))
                        (setq r t)
                      (setq ovs (cdr ovs))))
                  (not r)))
      (backward-word 1)
      (setq pos (point)))
    (goto-char pos)))

(defun add-false-postive ()
  "Add previous false positive to dict"
  (interactive)
  (goto-previous-spelling-error)
  (let* ((flyspell-info (flyspell-get-word))
         (word (car flyspell-info))
         (bounds (cdr flyspell-info)))
    (flyspell-do-correct 'save nil word (point) (car bounds) (cadr bounds) (point))
    (flyspell-delete-region-overlays (car bounds) (cadr bounds))
    (exchange-point-and-mark)
    (deactivate-mark))
```

Comment: This is excellent. I would recommend adding `(deactivate-mark)` to your `add-false-positive` function body, as currently it leaves the mark at the last flyspell error, which looks odd for people using transient mark mode.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak Ah yes, I have added it, thanks.